# How to sort data in laravel 7 eloquent using collection map?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have this peace of code to get comments and replies. I would like to know how can I sort the replies:

```
$comments = Comment::where([
            ['commentable_type', 'App\Models\Posts\Post'],
            ['commentable_id', $post->id],
            ['parent_id', null]
])->with('replies')
          ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
          ->take(10)
          ->get()->map(function($comments) {
                $comments->setRelation('replies', $comments->replies->take(3));                
                return $comments;
});
```

I tried do this:

```
$comments = Comment::where([
            ['commentable_type', 'App\Models\Posts\Post'],
            ['commentable_id', $post->id],
            ['parent_id', null]
])->with('replies')
          ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
          ->take(10)
          ->get()->map(function($comments) {
                $comments->setRelation('replies', $comments->replies->take(3));                                    
                $comments->setRelation('replies', $comments->replies)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
                return $comments;
});
```

And also

```
$comments = Comment::where([
            ['commentable_type', 'App\Models\Posts\Post'],
            ['commentable_id', $post->id],
            ['parent_id', null]
])->with('replies')
          ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
          ->take(10)
          ->get()->map(function($comments) {
                $comments->setRelation('replies', $comments->replies->take(3)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc'));
                return $comments;
});
```

But did not works.

Could you help me?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want the last three replies for each comment - this should work

```php
$comments = Comment::where([
        ['commentable_type', 'App\Models\Posts\Post'],
        ['commentable_id', $post->id],
        ['parent_id', null]
    ])->with(['replies' => function($query){
        $query->latest();
    }])
    ->get()
    ->map(function($comment) {
        $replies = $comment->replies;

        unset($comment->replies);

        $comment->setRelation('replies', $replies->take(3));
        
        return $comment;
    });
```

Comment: Hi, tks, but did not works, because this code limits 3 replies for all comments. I need that it limits 3 replies for each comment. My code works, but I dont know how sort results for replies.

Comment: The code provided will output 3 replies for each comment sorted in descending order starting with the latest - that's what I thought you want. Am still not able to understand what is your exact requirement

Comment: You got it right. But this code does not work as you say. This code return: Comment 1
 Reply 1
Comment 2
 Reply 2
Comment 3
 Reply 3

I wish Comment 1
 Reply 1
 Reply 2
 Reply 3
Comment 2
 Reply 1
 Reply 2
 Reply 3
Comment 3
 Reply 1
 Reply 2
 Reply 3
Comment 4
 Reply 1
 Reply 2
 Reply 3
Comment 5
 Reply 1
 Reply 2
 Reply 3

Comment: @Jader Have updated answer - try and let me know it works as per your requirement

Comment: Hi, this new solution is working fine. Thank you very much!